# How to execute .exe as "run elevated" (Not running as administrator) in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script to execute an .exe. It needs to "run elevated", not run as admin- I do not want the prompt of admin username/pswd.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Invoke-Expression "& `"\\filepath\vs_setup.exe`" \\filepath\vs_setup.exe /run"
```

If you right click on the actual .exe, some machines have the option of **"run elevated"**, depending on your access level, which uses the admin token so you don't get a prompt screen that needs you to input admin username and password.

Comment: What do you think "run elevated" means?

Comment: Try `Start-Process -FilePath "\\filepath\vs_setup.exe" -verb RunAs -ArgumentList @("/run")`. Running elevated and as admin are the same on Windows.

Comment: When I run as admin, it asks for username and password. When I right click and "run elevated", it does not ask for username and password.

Comment: Also, [do not use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath "\\filepath\vs_setup.exe" -verb RunAs -ArgumentList @("/run")` runs as admin and you have to input a admin username and password. This is not the same as right clicking on the application and selecting "run elevated", which silently uses the admin token for machines who have elevated rights (example: developer rights) when users aren't admins of their machines.

Comment: The `Run elevated` menu option you are seeing is not a standard part of the operating system. Do you have [this](https://download.beyondtrust.com/PBWD/Manuals/PBD_User_Guide_V5.3.pdf) installed? If that's the case it's a question for the vendor. Otherwise, the answer is that you cannot bypass the UAC prompt (this is by design).